# Почему происходит эта ошибка «The caller does not have permission»?

Tags: php, google-apps-script

Мне нужно вызвать google script через api, поэтому я сделал следующее

- Я создал приложение для Oauth
- Создал gs скрипт, сохранил
- Развернул как исполняемый api

Мой php код

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$service = new \Google_Service_Script($client);
$request = new \Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
$request->setFunction('myFunction');
$response = $service->scripts->run('idScript', $request);
```

И в конце получил такую ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The caller does not have permission", "errors": [ { "message": "The caller does not have permission", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }
```

Comment: А в консоле разработчика в разделе `Допустимый тип приложений` выбраны приложения?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov а можете скинуть ссылку где посмотреть Допустимый тип приложений

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/ вы должны получить токен, создать точку и разрешить использовать его веб ресурсам, лучше только определенным, или всем, что google не любит особо.

Comment: Я все это уже сделал

Comment: Ну так там есть приложения, разрешите для web иначе гугл запрещает доступ к данным, если сервер настраивается локально, то отключите ограничения совсем.